# Passing mutable char * to Python in SWIG

Tags: c++, python, swig

I have the a purely virtual class I need to implement in Python, so that it's called back from a C++ framework.

File `example.h`:

```
/** Abstract reader to be implemented */
class Reader {
public:
    /// Read maximum of `n` bytes into `c`
    virtual int read(char *c, int n) = 0;
    virtual ~Reader() {}
};

void test(Reader &r);
```

---

File `example.cpp`

```
#include "example.h"

void test(Reader &r) {
    char buf[] = {0, 0, 0};
    r.read(buf, 3);
}
```

---

SWIG Interface:

```
%module(directors="1") example
%{
#include "example.h"
%}

%feature("director") Reader;
%include "example.h"
```

---

Python test code:

```
import example
class ReaderImpl(example.Reader):
    def __init__(self):
        example.Reader.__init__(self)

    def read(self, c, n):
        ''' Demo impl '''
        print type(c)
        return 0

example.test(ReaderImpl())
```

The latter will print `<type 'str'>` which is of no use to me since I'm supposed to write into the buffer. So, the question is: is there a way to tell SWIG that I'd rather have something writeable for `char *`, maybe, like ctypes array?

Answer (score 3):

Check out section `31.7.4 String handling` from http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html#Python_nn48

The change is not that trivial because the length of the string can be changed. If you actually want a array or something like that check out the doc on how to define your own type mapping.

Considering the overheads of python mapping you might be better off(simpler code) with just returning a string from `read()`.

Comment: Thanks, I decided to go with my own type mapping. Unfortunately, changing the framework API is not an option (even though, I'd also consider writing some adapters for it, so that Python would return string).

Answer (score 1):

I resolved that with type mapping:

```
%typemap(directorin) char * {
    $input = PyInt_FromLong((unsigned long)$1;
}
```

As a result, the implementation will receive an integer which can be converted to a ctypes pointer as:

```
from ctypes import cast, c_char, POINTER

class ReaderImpl(example.Reader):
    def read(self, buf, n):
        ptr = cast(buf, POINTER(c_char))
        # populate ptr[0]...ptr[n-1]
```

Another option would be to inherit an intermediate class from `Reader` and implement `read` in terms of its purely virtual method that returns a string. That new method would be implemented in Python.